# Need Pagination Reference along with EqualTo Query/clause:

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Need Pagination Reference along with EqualTo Query/clause:

Here is my structure:

[image: DB Structure]

Granite, Greatness, Maxasd are the channel names and will be always Unique. You can assume there won’t be any duplicate entries.
Now on the front-end, I want to show all the channels created by the current logged user with pagination. Let’s assume that if the current logged user is Matthew, He should see only latest 5 channels (like channels Channel1 and Channel2 ….)

I tried with following syntax, but looks like I cannot mix the EqualTo and StartAt, EndAt.

***What I have done so far:***

**(WITHOUT PAGINATION)**

```
  firebase.database().ref('/channels' ).orderByChild('createdby').equalTo(‘Matthew’).on('child_added', function(snapshot)
```

The above code works perfectly pulling only the channels created by Matthew. The issue comes when I want to use a reference for pagination. (like the last shown channel name).

But actually, if I need to get the pagination, I tried the below and works perfectly as well.

**(WITH PAGINATION)**

```
fb.orderByChild('createdon').startAt().endAt(firsttimestamp).limitToLast(3).on("child_added", function(dataSnapshot) {
```

In the above code, firsttimestamp, is the reference which I showed lastly to the user, so I take that reference and populate the next batch.

**WHAT I NEED Now?**

So my challenge is how to modify the below query, so I can add a pagination reference same like above. Basically, How the above query should be modified, so I retain “EqualTo” and add “EndAt” with some timestamp? Or any other suggestions? 
* It is not allowing me to use EndAt along with EqualTo.

```
firebase.database().ref('/channels' ).orderByChild('createdby').equalTo(‘Matthew’).on('child_added', function(snapshot)
```

Please suggest how I can achieve the pagination when you have "EqualTo" clause. Basically, I need to show all the channels created by (CreatedBy field) with pagination (using the Limit clause).

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560932/how-to-paginate-firebase-query-which-contain-equalto-api/45908808#45908808