# How to paginate firebase query which contain equalTo() api

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm coding a shopping website with firebase.
I have a some categories and subcategory in the sidebar, which onClick them, posts feeds should be updated accordingly, ordered by time and just show posts from selected category.

post object on the firebase database :

```
    -KiKGQUZ4XaZPHxvOZD-addclose {
      categorie:0
      subCat: 2
      ....
    }
```

There's a lot of posts and i need to paginate them

To do it i should query like this:

```
  dbRef
    .orderByChild('categories')
    .equalTo(category)
    .limitToLast(QUERY.PAGINATION_COUNT)
    .on('value', (snapshot) => {
      cb(_toArray(snapshot).reverse());
    });
```

But i can not paginate with equalTo().

I think the solution should be :

```
  dbRef
    .orderByChild('categories')
    .equalTo(category)
    .startAt(lastFetchedItem.fbKey)
    .limitToLast(QUERY.PAGINATION_COUNT)
    .on('value', (snapshot) => {
      cb(_toArray(snapshot).reverse());
    });
```

But its not possible with firebase to do `equalTo` query and `startAt` in the same time

How to i can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing firebase realtime database schema.

I'm not sure but i think firebase intentionally doesn't release more apis. Its forcing you to double check your schema and improve it.

I have created a dedicated collection for categories and in the categories collection created separate node for each category.
Its what [firebase recommend](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) to structure your database.

Then put each new post into the corresponding category.

So i can easily use `OrderByKey()` in each category and sub category and paginate them using `startAt` or `endAt` apis

An another solution would be using firebase function and elastic search.
[FlashLight package](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) has been created for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/issues/68) it looks like this functionality is not possible and is not going to be added. You can do something like this though

1. Query your initial paging amount using equalTo
2. Query by key ending at your last visible key and filter the results if the category matches the one you want then add it, otherwise ignore it.

I wrote my code in Swift3, but had the same issue maybe my code will be helpful to others.

```
static func filterTableByCategory(tableNumber: String, category: String) {
        filteringRef.child(tableNumber).queryOrdered(byChild: "category").queryEqual(toValue: category).queryLimited(toLast: 9).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in

            if snap.exists() {
                currentTablePosts.removeAll()
                for child in snap.children {
                    let child = child as? DataSnapshot
                    if let post = child?.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        let posst = Post()
                        if let author = post["author"] as? String, let likes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String, let postDescription = post["postDescription"] as? String, let timestamp = post["timestamp"] as? Double, let category = post["category"] as? String, let table = post["group"] as? String, let userID = post["userID"] as? String, let numberOfComments = post["numberOfComments"] as? Int, let region = post["region"] as? String {

                            posst.author = author
                            posst.likes = likes
                            posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                            posst.postID = postID
                            posst.userID = userID
                            posst.fancyPostDescription = Helper.createAttributedString(author: author, postText: postDescription)
                            posst.postDescription = author + ": " + postDescription
                            posst.timestamp = timestamp
                            posst.table = table
                            posst.region = region
                            posst.category = category
                            posst.numberOfComments = numberOfComments
                            posst.userWhoPostedLabel = Helper.createAttributedPostLabel(username: author, table: table, region: region, category: category)

                            if let people = post["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                for(_, person) in people {
                                    posst.peopleWhoLike.append(person as! String)
                                }
                            }
                            currentTablePosts.insert(posst, at: 0)
                            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTableCollectionView"), object: nil)
                        } // end of if let
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                currentTablePosts.removeAll()
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTableCollectionView"), object: nil)
            }
        })
        filteringRef.removeAllObservers()
    }

    static func getMoreFilterByCategoryPosts(tableNumber: String, category: String, lastVisibleKey: String) {

        pagingReference.child(tableNumber).queryOrderedByKey().queryEnding(atValue: lastVisibleKey).queryLimited(toLast: 12).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in

            if snap.exists() {
                let currentNumberOfPosts = currentTablePosts.count
                for child in snap.children {
                    let child = child as? DataSnapshot
                    if let post = child?.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let cat = post["category"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String {
                            if cat == category && postID != lastVisibleKey {
                                let posst = Post()
                                if let author = post["author"] as? String, let likes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postDescription = post["postDescription"] as? String, let timestamp = post["timestamp"] as? Double, let table = post["group"] as? String, let userID = post["userID"] as? String, let numberOfComments = post["numberOfComments"] as? Int, let region = post["region"] as? String {

                                    posst.author = author
                                    posst.likes = likes
                                    posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                                    posst.postID = postID
                                    posst.userID = userID
                                    posst.fancyPostDescription = Helper.createAttributedString(author: author, postText: postDescription)
                                    posst.postDescription = author + ": " + postDescription
                                    posst.timestamp = timestamp
                                    posst.table = table
                                    posst.region = region
                                    posst.category = cat
                                    posst.numberOfComments = numberOfComments
                                    posst.userWhoPostedLabel = Helper.createAttributedPostLabel(username: author, table: table, region: region, category: category)

                                    if let people = post["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                        for(_, person) in people {
                                            posst.peopleWhoLike.append(person as! String)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    currentTablePosts.insert(posst, at: currentNumberOfPosts)
                                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTableCollectionView"), object: nil)
                                } // end of if let
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                print("snap == nil")
            }

        })
        pagingReference.removeAllObservers()

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment .. but your solution is not applicable

Comment: Because you may ignore more than 100 response in a real project for a request.